# WordPress Insert Post with WP CLI

Tags: wordpress, post, command-line-interface

I want to create a post by using WP CLI's eval-file command on a file with the contents below. However, it fails to create a post, and furthermore doesn't return an error even though the second parameter of wp_insert_post() is set to true. Please can someone explain?

```
<?php

echo 'This file is being evaluated';

$new_post = Array(
    'post-title' => 'New Post',
    'post-content' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Efficiens dici potest. Videmus igitur ut conquiescere ne infantes quidem possint. Aliter enim nosmet ipsos nosse non possumus. An haec ab eo non dicuntur? Non enim iam stirpis bonum quaeret, sed animalis. Duo Reges: constructio interrete. Cave putes quicquam esse verius.'
);

wp_insert_post($new_post, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, so it was simple:

Use post_title etc., not post-title (underscore vs hyphen!).